# What are the best sites to showcase my development skills?

Tags: asp.net

Besides stackoverflow, what are the best sites to showcase my development skills?

For those sites that are specific to a particular set of skills, I am a ASP.Net developer and I use c# primarily.

**Edit**:

Something to send potential employers, and something that they would find easily during a Google search of me.

Comment: How bout you make your own site to showcase your skills.  And I was unaware that this was a showcase.  I thought it was a resource.

Comment: Strange as it may sound, a few people were asked their SO reputation in job interviews.

Comment: Well yes, this is a resource, but with reputation, it also allows developers to showcase their skills

Comment: So helps you to keep your skills sharp.

Comment: oh ok... I suppose it is a reasonable indicator of how knowledgeable you are.

Comment: @Anurag thats not strange at all, its something that is becoming common, that or "What OSS projects have you contributed to". Its a nice way to get around the "I cant show you what I worked on because its the property of the company I worked for" dilemma.

Comment: Resource? I thought it was a game, it has achievements^H^H^Hbadges and is addicting!

Comment: @Mechko, believe it. SO is a great resource but now it has actualy become something I participate on more often than I lurk. Why? Because even if you have been involved since before SO went up, if your rep doesnt reflect it some jobs/usergroups look down on you a bit.

Comment: @Roger: Don't forget the Experience Points.

Comment: Aaron: I've been going for Pundit lately (case in point?), so I forgot about rep. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a blog, that would be an awesome resource for your future employers to know more about you and your work.

Also, if you're looking for a job, there are many cool sites where you can show not only your coding skills ([TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/), [GitHub](https://github.com/)) but also what you think ([Twitter](http://twitter.com/)), and maybe what your teammates think about you ([LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/)).

Again, with a blog you could keep all this links together in one place.

Answer (score 2):

- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)
- [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com)
- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)

There are many others as well.

Answer (score 1):

A web page, of course. get a github account. Pick up silverlight and make a cool game perhaps?

Comment: I agree with the website part.  Write something useful or cool and make it open source (unless you want to try and sell it).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may publish some of your projects in [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com). If you have chosen a right project I think it can show your talent

Answer (score 1):

Next time you take on a project that you don't mind being public, document your way through the project on a blog.  It would give employers a chance to see your work patterns.

Also, win a couple TopCoder competitions.  That might help

Comment: A friend actually got a job from his TopCoder ranking---but he was in the top 5 for a long time, and did well in some of their early yearly tournaments (the ones where 1st place alone got $100k).  FTROU, it's probably better as algorithmic practice.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.planetsourcecode.com used to be great but when I looked at it just now it seems like it has gone to the dogs.
http://www.codeproject.com is pretty poorly organised (in terms of site design) but if you want to draw attention to yourself it's pretty easy to find topics on there which aren't covered and could use a tutorial/example.
Consider contributing to existing established open-source projects on sites like SourceForge and CodePlex rather than starting your own. One which comes to mind that I looked at recently is http://anmar.eu.org/projects/sharpwebmail/ - it's a great project but sorely in need of a visual overhaul, which means more than just some updated JPEGs. Oxite was falling behind its roadmap targets from memory if you want another example of a good project to contribute to.

Answer (score 0):

what about publishing a good nice opensource 'product' at [google code](http://code.google.com/), [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/) or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)?